# RegEx for 6 Digits a Decimal and 1-4 more Digits

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried and tried to research this and tried many iterations of expressions and still can't seem to get it right. I give up, Please someone help.

I have a text box and on textbox change I have it replace the text with the regex.replace text 
i need the text box to Only allow \d{6} followed by a single . and then \d{1,4}

Accepts 123456.1,123456.12, 123456.123, 123456.1234

Does not accept 123.45612, aqwerty.12, 123456..12

Comment: Have you tried `\d{6}\.\d{1,4}`?

Comment: @"[^\d{6}\.\d{1,4}]"  will filter out all none numbers or "."'s but does not force the pattern 6 digits decimal 1-4 digits. as i can type "..........." or "12...12312.131." or "123456789"

Comment: @"^\d{6}\.\d{1,4}$", remove the `[]`

Answer (score 4):

have you tried this pattern? maybe you forgot to escape `.` with `\`

```
^\d{6}\.\d{1,4}$
```

[image]

Comment: Not for me, what is your C# code? Did you add an @ in front of the regex string? If not you should, otherwise \ will act as escapes.

Comment: private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string filteredtext =         Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"[^\d{6}\.\d{1,4}$]", "");
                    textBox1.Text = filteredtext;
                }

Comment: when i remove the [] it allows everything including symbols and letters. This regex seems to do no more then [^.0-9].

Comment: What if you try Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

Comment: Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);  Had the same effects. Is this just something I Can't to with RegEx?

Comment: I think you have your `Regex.Replace()` backwards. He doesn't want to remove the matches of this pattern, he wants to remove everything _except_ the matches.

Comment: i think you don't need *regex.replace* here since you want validation. use `Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^\d{6}\.\d{1,4}$")` which returns boolean. if it returns false, alert the user that he/she have entered invalid value.

Comment: The reason for the replace is to avoid a popup the code i have no is 95% working is STOPS all input that is not either a digit or a decimal. If anything other then a digit or a decimal is pasted or typed in it simply removes it. The only addition I want is to make it so you can't enter a decimal until AFTER 6 digits are entered. I know i can do this probably hundreds or other ways using ifs, lengths, and foreachs. I just figured i was  already using a regex so I wangted to try and further this code